# Java Program compiled successfully and class file is generated but no output in Command Prompt

Tags: java

I am a beginner to Java and learning how to run programs from Command Prompt.

I have written a basic Program as such..

```
public class MyfirstApp {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       System.out.print("I Rule");
       System.out.print("The World");
    }
}
```

Command i gave in CMD `javac MyfirstApp.java` it compiled successfully and class file is also generated. But there is no output in command Prompt. I mean 
I Rule The World " should be displayed right?Where it will be displayed?Will it be displayed or not?

Comment: Did you try running the application?

Comment: You say you compiled it, but did you run it afterwards?

Comment: By the way, your output will be "I RuleThe World", with no spaces.

Comment: @farukdgn:  You *really* don't need a JAR to run this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Compilation* is different than *execution*.  You've managed to successfully compile your code; now you just need to execute it.

The way to do this is by `java MyfirstApp` (or more generally, `java <classname>`).

Comment: Yes!!! Got the output on screen..This is what i understood now.For compiling the Java Program javac <space><classname>.java In my case javac MyfirstApp.java then class file is generated. For running the program java<space><classname> In my case java MyfirstApp .Thank you everyone.

Comment: @Sai Jayadeep - thanks are expressed by accepting answers - tick Makoto's answer