# Cannot print on console

Tags: java, cmd, javac

I've just installed JDK and set the PATH through the control panel to

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin`

Then, I tried to run some code i found online:

```
public class helloworldfirst {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }

}
```

using the Command Prompt like so: `javac helloworldfirst.java`
, but nothing was displayed in the Command Prompt and instead, a new file was created on my desktop.

Why was this file created?
Is it possible to prevent it from being created? How do I print "Hello World!" in the Command Prompt?

Comment: javac is the compiler. You have to run the created .class or .jar file with the java command.

Comment: all you did so far is compile the code. Now you have to run the compiled file. run java helloworldfirst

Comment: For increased clarity, run the command `java helloworldfirst` in the directory containing your output file.

Comment: Follow the next step in whatever Java guide you're reading, to actually *run* the code after compiling it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Program compiled successfully and class file is generated but no output in Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29195985/java-program-compiled-successfully-and-class-file-is-generated-but-no-output-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use `java` and not `javac`:

```
java helloworldfirst.java
> Hello, World!
```

note that this requires JDK11 or higher.

Java is a compiled language; anything but the simplest stuff goes through two steps: First code is compiled (this turns them into `.class` files), then those can be run. build systems and IDEs generally make this a smooth experience.

Comment: Since question actually specifies `jdk-15`, that's a good answer, but not everybody seeing this question will be using Java 15, so enhancing the answer to show pre-java 11 way would be good.

Comment: I don't see the point of that - whilst JDK8 is still more or less industry standard, someone doing such first steps that this is hard for them should have no business running JDK8 and almost never are. People don't go out of their way looking for old versions of things just for kicks.